# How to auto increment employeeID based on values already entered in database?

Tags: java, html, mysql

I have a html page and a servlet which is responsible for adding new employee information to a database. Currently, as you can see, the 4 digit employee ID is entered manually by this admin. Is there any way I can auto-generate this, based on values which are already in the database? E.g. if there is an employee with id 0001, then the 4 digit employee ID will automatically be filled out as 0002 or something along those lines? Thanks

Part of code from NewEmployee.html

```
<form action ="NewEmployeeAccount" method = "post"> 

    <table border ="1"> 
        <tr>
            <td>4 digit Employee ID:</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "employee_id"  pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="4 digit number: e.g. 1234" maxlength="4" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "firstName"  required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "lastName"  required></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Create Employee Account"/>
</form>
```

Part of code from NewEmployeeAccount.java

```
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.employee_info(employeeID, FirstName, LastName) values(?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, employee_id);
    ps.setString(2, firstName);
    ps.setString(3, lastName);
```

Comment: you should use mysql's [auto inrement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) syntax for that field. then you don't need user to enter anything for that field

Comment: You're confusing data storage and data display. Whatever the format of the displayed ID, you only need to store the significant figures. Youcef's idea is a terrible one.

Comment: he need something like that 000ID or 00ID so he need to make a varchar not auto-increment no max he need to make a piece of code witch generate this code, he has two solution one with java code, the other with a triger

Answer (score 1):

- Create the table as follows. The `auto_increment=1000` will tell MySQL to start inrementing the `employeeID` column starting from 1000 (four digit number).

  ```
  CREATE TABLE create table employee_info (
      employeeID int not null auto_increment,
      FirstName char(30) not null,
      LastName char(30) not null) auto_increment = 1000;
  ```
- After creating the table insert an initializer row into the table so that the counting is initialized:

  ```
  insert into employee_info (FirstName, LastName) values ('initializer', 'initilizer);
  ```
- From now on, before the page is displayed you query max value of the `employeeID`, add 1 to it and display it on the page in an readonly field:

  ```
  select max(employeeID) from employee_info
  ```
- Insert the new entry to the table when the page is submitted. This time the value you incremented manually will be generated and saved:

  ```
  insert into employee_info (FirstName, LastName) values ('newFirstName', 'newLastName');
  ```

This is just a work around and not an ideal solution. Especially, the first entry to the table should be documented well so that other users or you yourself a couple of months later know why you are using it.

This solution is based on the assumption that you can use 1000 as your starting ID. If you want to use numbers less than 1000 I don't know any automatic way of generating the key except you generate it in the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks! But what should I change in the html to display in a readonly field?

Comment: 1. change your html page to a JSP page. 2. create  a JavaBean (let us name it `EmployeeInfo` containing the properties `employeeID`, `FirstName`, and `LastName`. 3. create a Servlet, execute the above select query , create the JavaBean and initialize its `employeeID` property to the value of the query and put it into the HttpServletRequest object as its attribute. 4. dispatch the request to the JSP page 5. in the JSP page  fetch the bean and display the value. If you don't have experiance with JSP, leave me a comment (I will answer tomorrow, sorry no time today).

Comment: I have never used JSP, sorry!

Comment: [Here](http://www.studytonight.com/jsp/introduction-to-jsp.php) is a very easy and short tutorial to get you started. Just follow the `next` button at the bottom right corner. And [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=551) one is a 10 min. tutorial how you could use the expression language in a JSP page to populate the page with the JavaBean values. And leave me a message if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can set a column to AUTO_INCREMENT. If you have an integer value of 1 and a new record is added the value for this record in the specified column will be 2.

A table with an auto increment column can be created like this:

```
CREATE table `user`(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32),
    pass VARCHAR(256)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE payroll_system MODIFY COLUMN employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Then you don't have to enter employee_id value by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I display this value in the html page? In the field which says "4 digit Employee ID:"?

Comment: I think you should have data view for your saved data. where you will be showing data after fetching from database. Now you don't need that employee_id field in your form.